# Google apps script - Bookmark a selected image

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

How can I `addBookmark()` a selected image from Goole docs.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your situation, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
function myFunction() {
  const doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  const selection = doc.getSelection();
  if (!selection) return;
  selection.getRangeElements().forEach(e => {
    const ele = e.getElement();
    const type = ele.getType();
    if (type == DocumentApp.ElementType.TEXT) {
      doc.addBookmark(doc.newPosition(ele, e.getStartOffset()));
    } else if (type == DocumentApp.ElementType.INLINE_IMAGE) {
      doc.addBookmark(doc.newPosition(ele.asInlineImage().getParent(), 1));
    }
  });
}
```

- When you use this script, please select an inline image on Google Drive and run the script. By this, the bookmark is added to the inline image. And, when you select a text, the bookmark is added to the text.

#### Reference:

- [asInlineImage()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/element#asinlineimage)